# Get timeslots from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I am trying to get certain Dates that fit in timeslots from a table where

- the timeslot **starts** at the current DateTime **floored** to full hour
- the timeslot **ends** at the current DateTime **floored** to full hour **plus 2 hours**

so a DateTime that is `2011-06-24 09:21:40.020` could be between:

```
2011-06-24 09:00:00.000 AND 2011-06-24 11:00:00.000
```

Currently I've got this, but I think the nested `DATEADD` is a redundant. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
SELECT     dbo.Computer.ComputerName, dbo.Planned.DatePlanned
FROM       dbo.Computer INNER JOIN
           dbo.Planned ON dbo.Computer.ComputerID = dbo.Planned.ComputerID
WHERE      dbo.Planned.DatePlanned 
BETWEEN
(SELECT    DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
AND
(SELECT    DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, DATEADD(Hour, 2, GETDATE())), 0))
```

This should give me all ComputerNames and Planned Dates in the current active timeslot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is cleaner to define those two variables:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
DECLARE @End DATETIME = DATEADD(Hour, 2, @Start)

SELECT dbo.Computer.ComputerName, dbo.Planned.DatePlanned
FROM dbo.Computer 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Planned ON 
        dbo.Computer.ComputerID = dbo.Planned.ComputerID
WHERE dbo.Planned.DatePlanned 
BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a mathematically cleaner way to do it; but in terms of code smell you could write a UDF (supported since SQL 2000). You can get an ounce of extra performance from the UDF and use it in computed columns (provided it's schema bound in both cases).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateTimeHourFloor]
(
    @DateTime DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- A little more perf.
AS BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, @DateTime), 0);
END;
```

You could then use it as such:

```
SELECT     dbo.Computer.ComputerName, dbo.Planned.DatePlanned
FROM       dbo.Computer INNER JOIN
           dbo.Planned ON dbo.Computer.ComputerID = dbo.Planned.ComputerID
WHERE      dbo.Planned.DatePlanned 
BETWEEN    [dbo].[DateTimeHourFloor](GETDATE())
    AND    [dbo].[DateTimeHourFloor](DATEADD(Hour, 2, GETDATE()));
```